# How to kill a process from Cron

Tags: shell, cron, jobs

Usually I do like this:
`kill -9 $(ps aux|grep Firefox|awk '{print($2)}')`

But when I try following via cron, it does nothing.
`50 * * * * kill -9 $(ps aux|grep Firefox|awk '{print($2)}')`

Mind you the process with 'Firefox' that I am trying to kill is also started by some cron.

Comment: did you add that in /etc/crontab or in your user crontab?

Comment: You say something about an error, but you don't mention what the error is.  Also, is there a reason you kill it with the `KILL` signal, and why you're not using `pkill`?

Comment: ignore that part . assume I have always used awk '{print($2)}', ok let me simplify the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda simplified the question for your better understanding.

Comment: It probably kills the actual cron job (since it contains the string `Firefox`).  This is why I asked if there was a reason to not use `pkill` (which does not have this issue).

Comment: lets come to pkill later and help me understand this first.  My question is basically, how is the cron scenario different from running explicitly via terminal, there also it tries to kill `ps aux`  process but fails.